# Change constrains depending on screen size

Tags: ios, autolayout

I tried to solve this at my own, but I just really can not understand auto layout. I also searched here for a solution, but I could not find anyone with this similar problem (although I see a lot of people struggling with auto-layout). I want to make an app in landscape mode what is supported by every iPhone 5 and higher. I set up some constrains, with this as result:

[How it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgC28.png)

Above is the correct image on how it should be on every device. Can I set it relative to a screen size? I tried changing values with the multiplier, but that did not worked out well.

[How it is on bigger screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhlhL.png)

Here you can see how it is now. Because the values are absolute and not relative, I think it not changes... By the way, I am using " compact height" for building my landscape apps for iPhone, is that correct? Or is this the cause of this big trouble?

Comment: the part you shown wrong, which part is small? the label size or the font?

Comment: Are you doing all that with individual constraints? If so, I would strongly recommend switching it to a stack view. Also, it looks like you are only adapting the position of the menu items. Surely, the size of the items should be changing too?

Comment: to h44f33z: both label size and font are to small. But what really bothers me is that the label does not relatively moves when the screen size gets bigger. Do you know what I mean or should I provide more pictures? to Chris: Yes, what I am now doing is picking up every item and add constrains, is that the wrong way? I did not have heard from stack views before. Is that a better way of adding constrains than what I am doing now? Yes, the size of the items needs to change also. I just started with auto layout, I don't know a lot yet :(

Comment: I wouldn't say that what you are doing is wrong, but you're probably making life hard for yourself. There are lots of good stack view tutorials to be found. They are simple and powerful and specially designed to scale and arrange nicely for different screen sizes.

Comment: Ok, maybe I searched for the wrong places all the time. So to make it short: with stack view I could get this to work on all devices? And is compact height the correct setting for building landscape apps? Thank you anyway for your answer, I will search for tutorials for stack views.

Comment: Chris can you give me an example of a good tutorial? Most of the tutorials want to teach me how you can make an app for landscape AND portrait, but I just want it to work on landscape for every screen size....

Comment: There are lots of good tutorials. I think Apple's own documentation is one of the best that I've read: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/LayoutUsingStackViews.html I'll add an answer that might help you if you're struggling...

Comment: Ok I will read that now... But must I use the settings Any - Any?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick run through that might be more applicable to your needs than the general tutorials...

Create your elements on the storyboard and lay them out in roughly the right place:

[image]

Select items 1-4 and hit the stack view button, then select items 5-8 and do the same, Xcode is very good at guessing what you want so you'll get two vertical stack views, like this:

[image]

Select them both, hit the stack view button again and you'll get a horizontal stack view that contains your two vertical stack views:

[image]

Then select this stack view and the header and press the stack view button one last time to put them in another vertical stack view:

[image]

How you just need to adda few constraints to the outer stack view and then tweak the settings of each stack view. In this case, I've pinned the outer stack view 20 from the view edges, set the outer stack view to fill proportionally and everything else to fill equally, plus I've set the vertical stack views to centre alignment. You can play with all of these settings to get a result that you find pleasing:

[image]

This will now scale perfectly for any size screen:

[image]

I've just used labels for speed, but the same rules apply for images or whatever.

Hope that helps, stick with the tutorials and keep practicing until you figure it out, it will save you lots of time in the long run.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When adding stack views, it feels not really smooth. Some images gets bigger and loses the aspect ratio... Also, I designed some levels for this game. When adding stack views, I get that lines around the stack view that I don't want. Is this the best way?

Comment: And what settings do I need to use? Why is everyone avoiding this question?! I use Any - Any, is that correct?

Comment: The lines only appear in the preview, not the app. All of the other constraints such as aspect ratio can be adjusted afterwards to refine the look of your layout. Stack views first, then constraints. There is no definitive 'best way', but this would be my recommendation in this case.

Comment: Nobody is avoiding your question, try to stay polite. "Any-Any" relates to size classes, not stack views. That is a completely different question and not relevant to what I'm trying to help you with. Size classes would be more relevant if you wanted to use different orientations, this is all landscape so you don't need to go there.